# Is this considered code duplication?

Tags: java, switch-statement, code-organization

If I want to test multiple values of an `enum` using a case statement, and 80% of the case statements require two different `if` checks, is it considered poor coding to reuse that code over and over?

I actually used `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` and felt like the code gods would kill me.

Here is some perspective:

```
switch(value) {

   case value1:
   {
      if(something) { //do something; }

      if(somethingElse) { // do something else; }

      //unique for value1
   }
   break;

   case value2:
   {
      //unique for value2
   }
   break;

   case value3:
   {
      if(something) { //do something; }

      if(somethingElse) { // do something else; }

      //unique for value3
   }
   break;

   case value4:
   {
      if(something) { //do something; }

      if(somethingElse) { // do something else; }

      //unique for value4
   }
   break;

   case value5:
   {
      //unique for value5
   }
   break;

   default:
   break;
```

My `value` is randomly generated from the `enum` and is called a random amount of times.  The goal is for `value` to be any random 'value' and totally independent of other cases.

Comment: Can't you let your similar cases flow into each other?

Comment: It's obviously duplication, the question is whether or not it's worth fixing via a command pattern, code in the enum, etc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you elaborate?

Comment: First action should be to make one function for `if(something)` and `if(somethingElse)`

Comment: I can't tell if you forgot, simply omitted it or don't know, but there should be a `break` statement at the end of each `case`, unless you want the code to flow through (i.e. the code from `value2`, `value3`, `value4` and `value5` will be executed as well if `value1` is true if there are no `break` statements).

Comment: @Dukeling my production code has it, I just forgot to include in this snippit.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to put this duplicate code into a method.

```
public void yourFunctionCall() {
    //Could even pass the value if needed
    if(something) { //do something; }

    if(somethingElse) { // do something else; }
}
```

Then call this method in your case:

```
switch(value) {

case value1: {
    yourFunctionCall();
    //or yourFunctionCall(value1);
    //unique for value1
} //etc..
```

Answer (score 2):

If this a reusable piece of code, you're better off turning it into a method. If not, you could simply add another `switch case` covering the common code using fall-through as:

```
switch (value) {

   case value1:

   case value3: // using fall-through

   case value4:
   {
      if (something) { /* do something; */ }

      if (somethingElse) { /* do something else; */ }
   }
}

switch (value) {

   case value1:
   {
      // unique for value1
      break;
   }

   case value2:
   {
      // unique for value2
      break;
   }

   // other unique cases
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a function is probably better, but here's another way:

```
case value1:
case value3:
case value4:
  if(something) { /* do something */ }

  if(somethingElse) { /* do something else */ }

  if (value1)
  {
    //unique for value1
  }
  else if (value3)
  {
    //unique for value3
  }
  else // if (value4)
  {
    //unique for value4
  }
  break;

case value2:
  ...
```

Or with nested switch:

```
case value1:
case value3:
case value4:
  if(something) { /* do something */ }

  if(somethingElse) { /* do something else */ }

  switch(value)
  {
    case value1: /* unique for value1 */ break;
    case value3: /* unique for value3 */ break;
    case value4: /* unique for value4 */ break;
  }
  break;

case value2:
  ...
```

Use with care, I wouldn't really recommend either for production code.

Comment: It's for unit testing.. so not really going to be used outside of that.